# Synchronize Firefox bookmarks online

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to sync firefox add-ons and bookmarks between machines](https://superuser.com/questions/2528/best-way-to-sync-firefox-add-ons-and-bookmarks-between-machines)

Is there a free tool which can synchronize (import and export) bookmarks from Firefox online? I would like to maintain the same set of bookmarks between my home and company systems.

I would prefer a tools that stores all the bookmarks online with username and password and syncs the bookmarks in Firefox.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/2528/best-way-to-sync-firefox-add-ons-and-bookmarks-between-machines